# Error CS0182 Ошибка при объявлении двумерного массива в атрибуте [TestCase()], NUnit

Tags: c#, массивы, юнит-тесты, nunit, объявление

Пытаюсь написать тест к методу, принимающему на вход, двумерный массив и дающий на выходе видоизмененный массив той же размерности. Однако при вводе конкретного значения в [TestCase()] выдается Error CS0182, хотя при попытке определить такой же массив в теле метода никаких ошибок нет. Как передать в атрибут двумерный массив? Тесты пишу с помощью NUnut

```
    [TestCase(new double[2, 3] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }, 0 , new double[2, 3] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } })]
    public void RunTests(double[,] mas , double whitePixelsFraction, double[,] expectedMas)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(ThresholdFilterTask.ThresholdFilter(mas, whitePixelsFraction), expectedMas);         

    }
```

Comment: [TestCaseSource](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html)

Comment: В аттрибутах 2 интовых массива, а в методе масссивы double

Comment: В атрибуты можно пихать только constexpr значения, т.е. значения вычисляемые на этапе компиляции. Оператор new работает в рантайме, поэтому для атрибутов не пригоден. Попробуй передать массив в виде json или просто строкой, а в теле теста десериализуй его в массив. Ну или как посоветовали выше - TestCaseSource